# In IPA, what is the difference between ə and ʌ?

Tags: pronunciation, phonemes

In all the examples I've seen they seem to be the same sound.

Examples of ə:

- a in about
- a in comma

Examples of ʌ:

- u in run
- o in won

I am trying to decipher the difference between these sounds but they seem identical to me.  Is it because of my dialect (American English), or is there a very subtle difference that I should look out for?

Comment: It depends on your dialect. Many dialects of American English use exactly the same sound for /ə/ and /ʌ/ (I use slightly different ones, although I use /ʌ/ for *comma*). Some dialects of British English pronounce /ʌ/ with a vowel that sounds to me more like the one in spa.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In English, the only real difference between these two is that [ʌ] occurs in stressed syllables, and [ə] occurs in unstressed syllables.  There is a slight acoustic difference between the two ([ʌ] is supposed to be a tiny bit lower and possibly backer than [ə]), but it is so slight that it is virtually indistinguishable.

Also note that many full vowels become [ə] when unstressed in English (e.ɡ. [sɔlɪd], but [səlɪdɪfaɪ]).

(This distinction is only for English, in other languages these phonemes can pattern completely differently.)

Comment: The rule about the unstressed [ʌ] versus stressed [ə] does not always hold true. For instance "unfair" [ʌnˈfɛər]. But I would agree that the difference between the two sounds really is insignificant.

Comment: I'm teaching myself phonetics, and am really confused on this point. From what I can see on wikipedia, your answer appears to be wrong, so I guess I must be misunderstanding something. /ʌ/ is a back vowel, whereas /ə/ is central. I'm a speaker of British English (from the South), and the sounds are clearly distinguishable. I can also see how /ʌ/ gets replaced by /ə/ in some words that get unstressed, like 'but' being /bʌt/ when stressed and /bət/ when unstressed, but I'm guessing there are a lot of words where /ʌ/ is unstressed. 'Pickup truck' for starters.

Comment: I forgot to an include a link to the wikipedia page I was referencing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_unrounded_vowel

Comment: OK, I think I've found the answer. In Many North American accents, the vowels are barely distinguishable. However in RP and other accents, they are clearly distinguishable.

Comment: However, I was wrong to call it a back vowel. It is a central vowel. From [wikipedia][1]: "Before World War II, the /ʌ/ of Received Pronunciation was phonetically close to a back vowel [ʌ]; this sound has since shifted forward towards [ɐ]". Also "In transcriptions for some languages (including several dialects of English), this symbol [/ʌ/] is also used for the near-open central vowel." So if I understand correctly, when talking about the English language we write /ʌ/ but should probably be writing /ɐ/. 
[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_unrounded_vowel

Comment: @Benjamin That's not unstressed; the _u_ in ‘unfair’ has secondary stress. Schwa occurs only in fully unstressed syllables.

Comment: Who pronounces "solid" as [sɔlɪd]? All the dictionaries I've checked say it has the LOT vowel, which would usually be transcribed as [ɑ] or [ɒ].

Comment: @herisson Many British people and Austrailians pronounce /ɒ/ as something more like [ɔ] than [ɒ]  Also notice that LOT and FATHER are only merged in America; for Brits for example the 2 vowels are quite different (and so the /ɒ/ or LOT is nothing like the /ɑ/ of FATHER)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You may be interested to learn that this answer’s question is cited at the very top of [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt66Je3o0Qg) by Geoff Lindsey, who I believe was long ago one of John Wells’s PhD students. Lindsey generally knows what he’s talking about better than most, but he's a professional at this so you should expect nothing less. :) I quite like it when he backs up some of his more “surprising” positions by showing actual acoustic readouts of utterances from various speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Upon being stressed, the schwa sound "ǝ" turns out to be a little bit longer as in "buttock", "number", etc. But in American English the difference is not so phonetically noticeable as it is in many British dialects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is some people who use something other than General American English, (British?) see words like the 'a' in sof*a* or *a*dore as an ə using, but in GAE that's not really the case. in British 'sofa' would clearly be 'soʊfʌ' because they seem to lengthen the final *a* more than GAE. In many cases there isn't a recognizable difference between the two in GAE. Take a word like 'columbus'. In GAE that would be kəlʌmbəs. GAE's ʌ is shorter than British ʌ but is still longer than GAE's ə.

Comment: Do you really mean you cannot hear the difference between an *ə* and an *ʌ* in British English? It's true that some UK speakers pronounce them the same, but for the ones who pronounce them differently, there is a *ə* in *sofa*. Listen to the difference between the strong form and the weak form of *but* in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/but). Those are different vowels. Even if they lengthen the *ə*, it's still a *ə*.